# Adding function to controllers in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add function to controller in angularJS, the way I think should be working but sadly not.

Here is my code.

```
//this is working.
$scope.adddata = function () {
    $scope.names.push({name:$scope.newdata.name,city:$scope.newdata.city});
    //$scope.names.push($scope.newdata);
}


//this is not working
function adddata() {
$scope.names.push({name:$scope.newdata.name,city:$scope.newdata.city});
//$scope.names.push($scope.newdata);
}
$scope.adddata = adddata();
```

Both functions above are in the definition of controller, hence $scope variable is available.

Can I only use `$scope.functionname = functionname(){....}`

or I can create a function and later assign it to controller / scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `$scope.adddata = adddata;` (no parentheses). Using the parentheses will assign the *result* of calling `adddata()` to the scope variable, which is undefined (`adddata()` does not return a value).

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
$scope.adddata = adddata;
```

instead of:

```
$scope.adddata = adddata();
```

Don't invoke the function, pass a reference to it.