# send value to controller in angularjs and return array

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I want send cod to controller and return array

When pressing a `li` you have to send a code to the controller, in this case I am setting the example 7. Once the code has arrived at the controller I will have a list that I have to show in a ng-repeat in table

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

    app.value('studentInfo', [
      { id: 1, name: 'Mahedee Hasan', credit: 20, semester: '8th' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Enamul Haque', credit: 15, semester: '7th' }
    ]);

    app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'studentInfo', function ($scope, studentInfo, $http, $window) {
        $scope.myClickList = function () {
            $scope.studentInfo = studentInfo;
        };

        var Cod = "7";
        $scope.myDataCountry = [];
        $scope.ButtonCountry = function (Cod) {
            $http.
                post("/Country/Angular", { CodH: Cod }).success(function (result) {
                $scope.myDataCountry = result;
            });
        };

    }]
  );
</script>
```

**VIEW**

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#calificaciones" ng-click="ButtonCountry ()"><span>Country</span></a></li>


    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="C in myDataCountry">
        <td>{{C.ID}}</td>
        <td>{{C.Country}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public JsonResult Angular(string codCountry)
    {

        var country = (from a in dbCountry.Country
                         where a.CodPersona == codCountry
                         select a.Country).ToList();

        return Json(country , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[I tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483988/how-to-return-value-from-service-to-controller-in-angularjs) and [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160640/adding-function-to-controllers-in-angularjs)

Comment: The `ng-click` is on an element that is outside the scope of the controller. The inline array annotation of the controller doesn't match the dependency injection.

Comment: The `.success` method is [deprecated and removed from V1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Comment: What is the name of your MVC Controller?  Is it CountryController?

Answer (score 0):

First, your li element isn't inside your app directive, which means it will not detect the function, you need to make sure that your li element is within the app scope

```
<!-- li is outside the scope --> 
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#calificaciones" ng-click="ButtonCountry(1)"><span>Country</span></a></li>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<!-- end --> 

<!-- li is within the scope --> 

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#calificaciones" ng-click="ButtonCountry(1)"><span>Country</span></a></li></ul> 
<!-- end -->
```

of course, you need to alter your html elements, meaning `ul` parent of the `li` most be included as well.

your Action url is wrong, your controller shows that action name is `CalificacionesAngular` but you are using `Angular` for some reason, another thing I notice you never passed the code to your function which means 
this

```
ng-click="ButtonCountry ()" 
 //should be this 
ng-click="ButtonCountry('thecode')"
```

and the data you are posting isn't similar to the parameter name,
you have to change this

```
post("/Country/Angular", { CodH: Cod })
//to this 
post("/Country/CalificacionesAngular", { codCountry: Cod })
```

there might be some more issues, these are the one I could see so far, please debug and provide more details about the error you are getting.
A good example you can check as well is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456250/how-to-make-angular-post-to-c-sharp-asp-net-mvc-controller?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Perform-HTTP-POST-to-Controller-using-AngularJS-http-POST-service-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx), and I suggest reading about [Directives](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp), [Binding](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp), [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp), and [Events](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp)

Comment: The `ng-click` is on an element that is outside the scope of the controller. The inline array annotation of the controller doesn't match the dependency injection.

Comment: thanks george, I just noticed that, I will edit my answer